# PHP: Cannot reach debug breakpoint with Psysh

Tags: php, debugging

I am trying to insert breakpoints into my code via Psysh. I followed the [Psysh documentation](http://psysh.org/) and installed it successfully via composer. I have composer and psysh available in any shell. Per the documentation I inserted a breakpoint into my code:

```html
<?php

  function hello(){
    echo 'Hello from Inside the Function';
    eval(\Psy\sh());
  }
  hello();
  
?>
```

When I run `php file.php` I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Psy\sh()`

It's definitely not a PATH issue because I can access Psysh interactive shells from any terminal. Why doesn't my php script know about Psysh?

Comment: Where is the `include 'vendor/autoload.php'` line?

Comment: @shukshin.ivan: I do not know what that is. Can you give me more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a
>   `vendor/autoload.php` file. You can simply include this file and start
>   using the classes that those libraries provide without any extra work:
>   `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';`

Composer installs library into `vendor` directory and generates a file, that helps to use the code. You have to include autoload file at the top of your simple script, otherwise it won't work.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: Ooops, I see the laravel tag. Why do you write code as a plain php script, not as a part of laravel app?

Comment: I figured Laravel users would know how to get PsySH working because they most likely use it a lot. I'm learning PHP right now outside of any framework.

Comment: I finally got it working: I had to install composer locally to my project, add a `composer.json` file and then run `composer install`. Then as you said, had to add `require('vendor/autoload.php');`. Thanks for leading me down the right path.